# Align title in the center of the tab

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

With extjs 5, by default, the tab title is aligned to the center.

With extjs 6 I can not get the same result and the titleAlign config does not work.

I tried to solve with tabConfig that although it is not available in the extjs 6 documentation it still works.

Any idea how to solve it?

Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2oo3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
style: {
    'text-align': 'center'
}
```

in your `tabConfig`. Here's the [**FIDDLE**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2ooa)

Comment: Thanks. Works fine.

Comment: Here is the preferred way to handle this https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2oou. You don't need tabConfig on each tab, nor do you need the styling in each tabConfig area. Styling should be handled on the parent Ext.tab.Panel object. Though doing it as in the comments fiddle does work it also creates more in changing/modifying as the code base grows. I've entered a bug report with Sencha on this as titleAlign is clearly not working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a bug. The tab button is represented by the [Ext.tab.Tab](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/classic/Ext.tab.Tab.html) class.

> Represents a single Tab in a Ext.tab.Panel. A Tab is simply a slightly
>   customized Ext.button.Button, styled to look like a tab.

And like all the buttons it has the [textAlign](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/classic/Ext.tab.Tab.html#cfg-textAlign) config, the one that you are looking for. It says that by default it has the `center` value, but it doesn't seem to work. Although [left](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2oo8) and [right](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2oo7) values do seem to work.

**EDIT**
This is a css bug, to apply a global fix just append this rule to the application:

```
.x-tab-button-center {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.I also think it's a bug.

Comment: is this modern or classic, as classic should be left, modern should be center. (different audience and history for each framework)